# argparse's "required" ignored in the help screen?

Tags: python, argparse

Consider the following code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', required=True, nargs=1)
parser.parse_args(['-h'])
```

Why am I getting the following output even if I said that `-o` is required?

```
usage: test.py [-h] -o O

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -o O
```

I would expect the help text to say that `-o` is required.

Comment: This is not what I wanted to ask about. The question is why it says it's optional, not required.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the help flag is special-cased to ignore the rest of the arguments, because the expectation is that they don't matter since all you're going to do is print the help and then quit immediately.

Comment: Still, the help screen is clearly wrong.

Comment: Just as a recomendation [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) is a really nice library to build CLIs

Comment: I'd say it doesn't show enough information, but not that it's wrong. It doesn't say that `-o` is optional... It just doesn't specify.

Comment: It's under "optional arguments".

Comment: Oh, hah, didn't notice that bit. Yeah that's messed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [issue #9694 on the Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue9694), as yet unfixed. You can read more there. Note that the usage line does correctly indicate that the switch is required (if it weren't, the usage line would read `usage: test.py [-h] [-o O]` instead of `usage: test.py [-h] -o O`).

For working around it, you can [use argument groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-groups) which can be given a `title`. As the example shows at the linked page, this allows you to create groups with your choice of name instead of the default `positional arguments` and `optional arguments` groupings.

Comment: The patch languishes, in part because no one has proposed a simple, well accepted, alternative pair of names.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the paradigm for `argparse` is that the required arguments are passed in positionally, and the arguments passed as options should be *optional*.  The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required) even discourage setting the `required` flag, considering this 'bad form'.

I can only suggest that the misleading help message generated is a minor shortcoming in argparse, you could possibly create a ticket for it on python's bug tracker.

You can override the default usage message if it is crucial for you to have a *required option*.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to best change (parts of) the default usage message of an `ArgumentParser` object?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that there isn't a 'required arguments' group.  The 2 default groups are labeled (for better or for worse)

```
positional arguments
optional arguments
```

There are actually 4 'requirement' alternatives - normal optionals, normal positionals, required optionals, optional positionals.  If the names are confusing, stick with the first two. :)

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo', help='a positional argument')
reqgroup=parser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
reqgroup.add_argument('-o', required=True, help='required optional')
parser.add_argument('-n',  help='normal optional')
parser.add_argument('bar',nargs='?', help='optional positional argument')
parser.print_help()
```

produces:

```
usage: ipython3.5 [-h] -o O [-n N] foo [bar]

positional arguments:
  foo         a positional argument
  bar         optional positional argument

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -n N        normal optional

required arguments:
  -o O        required optional
```

These alternatives are symbolically shown in the usage line, without the (potentially) confusing labels.

For what it's worth, the distinction between 'optionals' and 'positionals' is deeply imbedded in the `argparse` code.  One kind is identified by a flag string ('-f','--foo'), the other is identified by position.  The fact that one or the other is 'required' is superficial.  The only thing that makes some `optionals` 'required' is a bit of error checking at the end of parsing.